# Add live time with name of countries in JQVMAPS

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jqvmap

I want to add the current time to the country name in `JQVMAP`. Like this: `Eqypt-05:30 AM`

By default, when we hover the mouse over a country, it only shows the country name in world map. I also want to add the current time. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Pleasing to consult the documentation regarding:

```
onRegionOver: function(event, code, region)
    {
      // log out the region and or code to see the ID
      if (window.console) console.log( region );
    },
```

http://jqvmap.com/

youll need to do a time conversion hash/object based on element ID or similar

```
var foo = { "jqvmap1_thisID";"+5","jqvmap1_anotherID":"-2" };
```

then do the conversion

(not writing all the pseudo code)

OR you could have script that sets the labels onload, and then updates (settimeout 5000), though this is not ideal at all.

good luck!
Bo